# On the convergence of a series of function with exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to study the convergency of the following series, $\sum n e^{-x\sqrt{n}}$, but I can't figure out how to start since none of the tests that I know to study convergency seems to work. Any help/hint would be appreciated

Comment: For $x>0$ use: $e^{x\sqrt n} \geq \frac {(x\sqrt n)^{5}} {5!}$.

Comment: The integral test would work.

Comment: How would you use the integral test? I've never heard of that

Answer (score 0):

For a given $x\in\mathbb R$, let $f:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f_x(t)= te^{-x\sqrt t}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_x(n)$ converges if and only if $\int_1^\infty f_x(t)\ \mathsf dt$ does (this is the "integral test" as mentioned by @Claude Leibovici in the comments). To compute this integral, substitue $u=\sqrt t$, then
$$
\int_1^\infty te^{-x\sqrt t}\ \mathsf dt = 2\int_1^\infty u^3 e^{-ux}\ \mathsf du.
$$
Integrating by parts, we find that the above integral converges to
$$
2 e^{-x}x^{-4} (6 + x (6 + x (3 + x)))
$$
if and only if $x>0$, and hence the series in question converges if and only if $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$\sum n e^{-x\sqrt{n}}$
converges if
$e^{-x\sqrt{n}}
\lt \dfrac1{n^3}$
for all large enough $n$.
Taking logs, this is
$-x\sqrt{n} < -3\ln(n)
$
or
$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}
\lt \dfrac{x}{3}
$
and this follows from,
for any $c > 0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(n)
&=\int_1^n \dfrac{dt}{t}\\
&<\int_1^n \dfrac{dt}{t^{1-c}}\\
&=\int_1^n  t^{c-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{t^c}{c}\big|_1^n\\
&<\dfrac{n^c}{c}\\
\end{array}
$

If we put $c=\frac14$,
this is
$\ln(n)
\lt 4n^{1/4}$
or
$\dfrac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}
\lt 4n^{-1/4}
$.

Therefore,
if
$4n^{-1/4}
\lt \dfrac{x}{3}
$
or
$n
\gt (12/x)^4
$,
$e^{-x\sqrt{n}}
\lt \dfrac1{n^3}
$
so the sum converges.